# SQL deadlocking..in single user mode now

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Couple of databases produced an error this morning whilst running in Single User Mode.  Due to the following error I am unable to do anything :(

```
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 68, Line 1
Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I receive that error when trying the following (using the Master Database as a Sys Admin):

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

For the sake of it I have tried Restarting the SQL Server, I have tried killing any processes and I have even tried resetting the single user myself:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

The job which was running was designed to copy the database and put it in single user mode immediately to try and make it faster.

Anyway I can remove the locks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok,  I will answer my own.

I had to use the following:

```
sp_who
```

which displayed details of the current connected users and sessions, I then remembered about Activity Monitor which shows the same sort of stuff...Anyway that led me away from my desk to some bugger who had maintained connections to the database against my wishes...

Anyway once I had shut the PC down (by unplugging it...deserved it) I could then run the SQL to amend it into `MULTI_USER` mode (using system admin user):

```
USE Master
GO

ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

FYI for those who care, this can be used to immediately set the DB to `SINGLE_USER`:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
```

Further details, if you know the process id you can use `kill pid`:

```
kill 62
```

Bare in mind SSMS creates a process for your user as well, in my case this was being rejected due to another.

EDIT:  As Per Bobby's recommendations we can use:

```
sp_Who2
```

This can show us which process is blocked by the other process.

Comment: If you use sp_Who2 you can find out which process is blocked by which other process in the "BlkBY" category. Just a FYI.

Comment: Cheers Bobby, will add that in for info.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Still cannot make this work.  Even after running EVERYTHING it still says it cannot make this work because the database is running in single-user mode.  I'm using SQL Server 2005. :-/

Comment: What does sp_who2 display?  Does it report successful when executing the commands above or do you get an error?  What is the setting of sql server max concurrent connections, there are a few other stack exchange question/answers which might lead you down other paths

Answer (score 23):

Had the same problem.  This worked for me:

```
set deadlock_priority high; -- could also try "10" instead of "high" (5)
alter database dbname set multi_user; -- can also add "with rollback immediate"
```

From ideas/explanation:

[http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2014/03/06...](https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/sql-server-alter-database-in-single-user-mode-to-multi-user-mode/)

[http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2014/04/07/...](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pearlknows/2014/04/07/help-i-m-stuck-in-single-user-mode-and-can-t-get-out/)

Comment: Oh boy you just saved my life! I couldn't put the production DB back into multiuser after something went wrong..

With a bit more time i found, i alrady used the following commands to recover a DB, but your solution is more slick:

`ALTER DATABASE dbname SET EMERGENCY`

`DBCC CHECKDB (dbname, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS`

`ALTER DATABASE dbname set multi_user`

Answer (score 0):

tanks a lot.

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH ---- could also try "10" instead of "high" (5)
GO
ALTER DATABASE  SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
ALTER DATABASE  SET MULTI_USER
GO

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32831658)

Answer (score -1):

When related system processes are at dead block scenario.
SPID 15 & SPID 29 - both are background SysProcesses.

This helps in such cases:

```
--------- START OF CMDs--------   
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH ---- could also try "10" instead of "high" (5)  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE  
GO  
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET MULTI_USER  
GO   
-------------------------- END OF CMDs ------------------
```

[Blocking Case with an User DB RESTORE process putting DB in Single_User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoT5x.png)